# Segue from UITableViewCell to UIWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to segue from my TableView to a specific WebView depending on which row was selected. The object (Athlete) data is being parsed from a JSON file.

I've tried the following, the UIWebView screen loads, but it's blank, not sure what I'm missing, I'm new to Swift and coding, appreciative of any help, thanks!

snippet from UITableView Controller code:

```
let rosterLinksSegue = "toRosterWebView"


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == rosterLinksSegue,
    let destination = segue.destination as? RosterLinksViewController,
        let rosterURLIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    {
        destination.athleteURL = Athlete.Key.rosterURL
    }
}
```

ViewController (containing UIWebView) code:

```
class RosterLinksViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var rosterLinksWebView: WKWebView!

var athleteURL = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(athleteURL)")!)

    rosterLinksWebView?.load(request)

}
}
```

No error messages currently.

Comment: set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and check if athleteURL was actually assigned and it is not equal to ""

Comment: I am not fully following the question, can you give us more details on what it looks like?

Comment: @Soroush I added the breakpoint, but I'm not sure what to look for?

Comment: @Jonathan sorry, so from the TableViewCell lists information about an athlete, when the cell is tapped a segue is triggered to go to the next ViewController which has a UIWebView, I would like that UIWebView to display a specific webpage that is associated with that athlete (their roster page URL), does that make sense?